# Second level depth pure function?

Tags: function-construction, pure-function

I have the following working construction:

```
Select[ln125, # == Nearest[ln125, 551.748][[1]] &]
```

Here, `ln125` is a one dimensional list.

What I want further is to apply this construction not only to `ln125`, for example, but for a list of `{ln125,ln126,ln127}`.

Let's say,

```
f[list_]:=Select[list, # == Nearest[list, 551.748][[1]] &]
```

I want to do this:

```
f /@ {ln125,ln126,ln127}.
```

The question is: is it possible to acheive my goal only using pure functions? That is, without defining dummy function (`f` in my case)? The problem is that definition of `f` already  has pure function (as a criteria for `Select`) and, thus, there should be two pure function of different depths (don't know how to name it correctly) at once. In other words, I want to turn the `list` variable into `#` but in a way that *Mathematica* can distinguish which `#` goes with each different pure function.

Comment: Yes if you use the full form `Function`.

Answer (score 19):

In can be done in a terse way with nested pure functions:

```
lists = RandomReal[{0, 10}, {3, 10}]
```

> {{3.35338, 2.82572, 0.152277, 1.19036, 9.88211, 6.55398, 8.11855, 
>     0.793288, 9.04547, 6.42518}, {4.95417, 7.73982, 5.58323, 3.09912, 
>     5.44546, 8.88474, 2.67437, 8.20605, 4.55918, 1.95303}, {2.53793, 
>     6.67839, 8.71033, 8.4877, 0.634367, 7.99796, 4.74131, 0.679337, 
>     8.29468, 9.91209}}

```
Select[#, With[{aList = #}, # == Nearest[aList, 5.][[1]] &]] & /@ lists
```

> {{6.42518}, {4.95417}, {4.74131}

Using `With` to insert expressions into `Function`, which has the `HoldAll` attribute, is trick that is useful to keep in mind.

Answer (score 15):

You can use the form `Function[{x,y,z}, body]` to define a pure function with formal parameters `x,y,z` ( see [Documentation >> Function](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html))

Let

```
 lists = {ln125, ln126, ln127} = RandomReal[{0, 10}, {3, 10}]
 (* {{1.72286, 5.24912, 8.87257, 5.77593, 6.31276, 1.77914, 2.06393,
      0.328725, 9.46436, 4.96257}, 
     {1.71171, 2.54337, 5.93807, 9.46774,  6.99601, 2.76927, 7.58995,
      1.25785, 2.09789, 9.32326}, 
     {6.9821, 8.62002, 2.0763, 8.9402, 4.36728, 3.8571, 4.4175,
      7.15698, 7.64633, 5.23772}} *)
```

Define, (with `4.` playing the role of `551.748` in your example):

```
 f2 = Function[{x}, Select[x, # == Nearest[x, 4.][[1]] &]]
 f2 /@ lists
 (* {{4.96257}, {2.76927}, {3.8571}} *)
```

or

```
  f3 = With[{temp = Nearest[#1, 4.`][[1]]}, Select[#1, # == temp &]] &
  f3 /@ lists
  (* {{4.96257}, {2.76927}, {3.8571}} *)
```

Answer (score 9):

To clarify one of the answers. Note there is no way to distinguish both `#` inside `# == Nearest[#, 551.748][[1]]` in

```
Select[#, # == Nearest[#, 551.748][[1]] &] &
```

as you already noted. So, you need to give the outermost `#` a name and Function[...] is just for that. This one works:

```
Function[{l}, Select[l, # == First[Nearest[l, 551.748]] &]]
```

Personally, I don't like the `With` *trick* above: if you need to give it a name, use the  language construct for that. Then you do:

```
Function[{l}, Select[l, # == First[Nearest[l, 551.748]] &]] /@ {ln125,ln126,ln127}
```

Note that a Function[...] is already a (...&), so you don't need the usual ...& /@..., just Function[...] /@.

**P.S** If you do this often, this is, fix a value (i.e. `First[Nearest[l, 551.748]]`) inside another function of two or more parameters (i.e. `Equal` in your case) to have a function of the free parameters, then the following can be useful

```
FixCurry[f_, v_] := f[v, ##] &;
```

So, `FixCurry[Equal, 3]` is `Equal[3,#] &`. And this can be used in your case like

```
Select[#, FixCurry[Equal, First[Nearest[#, 5.]]]] & /@ {ln125,ln126,ln127}
```

which avoids the inner `(..&)` via the `FixCurry` construct. If you wonder how this could be used in other contexts, notice that the first argument to FixCurry can be a pure function with the `(...&)` syntax. In your example, more verbose but equivalent,

```
Select[#, FixCurry[#1 == #2 &, First[Nearest[#, 5.]]]] & /@ {ln125,ln126,ln127}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The "working construction" `Select[list, # == Nearest[list, value][[1]] &]` will give a list of the form `{nearestvalue, nearestvalue, ...}`, in which the nearest value is simply repeated the number of times it appears in `list`.

If `lists` contains several lists and all you want is the value in each list that is nearest to `value` then

```
nearestvals = Nearest[#, value][[1]]& /@ lists
```

will give you a list of those values. If you also want the repeat counts then

```
MapThread[{#2, Count@##}&, {lists, nearestvals}]
```

will give `{{nearestvalue, count}, {nearestvalue, count}, ...}`, with a pair for each list in `lists`.

Comment: Best answer. A NearestFunction already returns those list elements which are the nearest to a given value. Wrapping a Select around a NearestFunction to select the whole NearesFunction output is not particularly clever.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `NearestTo` with `Composition`.

With

```
SeedRandom[123]
{ln125, ln126, ln127} = RandomReal[{500, 600}, {3, 10}];
```

Then

```
First@*NearestTo[551.748] /@ {ln125, ln126, ln127}
```

> ```
> {546.671, 562.827, 549.18}
> ```

or without `First` if you want the nested list.

```
NearestTo[551.748] /@ {ln125, ln126, ln127}
```

> ```
> {{546.671}, {562.827}, {549.18}}
> ```

Hope this helps.