# Pure function inside another pure function

Tags: functions, function-construction

I have the following working expression:

```
In[15]:= Length[Select[IntegerPartitions[10],First[#1]==5&]]
Out[15]= 7
```

But, instead of using the constant 5 I want to map all values from 1 to 10 into this function. If I nest the pure function inside another it doesn't work:

```
In[18]:= Map[Length[Select[IntegerPartitions[10],First[#]==#&]]&,Range[10]]
Out[18]= {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
```

What is the way to do this?

Comment: You may need to use the variant form Map[Function[{x},...,First[#]==x&]]],...].

Comment: This variant seems to work. `Map[
 With[{a = #}, 
   Length[Select[IntegerPartitions[10], First[#] == a &]]] &, 
 Range[10]]

Out[257]= {1, 5, 8, 9, 7, 5, 3, 2, 1, 1}`

Comment: The name is not virtual function but Pure Function in a Mathematica context.

Comment: Possibly duplicate [(16947)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16947).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can have a pure function inside a pure function even in this case, you just can't have the name of the parameter being "#" in both. This works:

```
Map[Function[x, 
  Length[Select[IntegerPartitions[10], First[#] == x &]]], Range[10]]
```

Comment: Just a nit to pick since I think someone unused to Mathematica might get confused, I think it’d be better to say that “the parameter `#` in the outer function gets overwritten in the inner function `#` and so it needs to be bound to a different name either via `Function[x, ...]` or `With[{x=#}, ...]`”.

Answer (score 11):

**Using *Curry* or *OperatorApplied***

Pure function nesting is one of the use cases for [Curry](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Curry.html), introduced in version 11.3:

```
Length[
  Select[IntegerPartitions[10], Curry[First[#] == #2 &][#]]
] & /@ Range[10]

(* {1, 5, 8, 9, 7, 5, 3, 2, 1, 1} *)
```

`First[#1] == #2 &` defines a two argument pure function.  By wrapping `Curry[...][#]` around this, we bind the inner slot reference `#2` to the value of the outer slot reference `#`.  After binding, we are left with a single argument function that is suitable for use with `Select`.  For example, in one mapping iteration the outer `#` has the value `7` and the curried function `Curry[First[#1] == #2 &][7]` is essentially equivalent to `First[#1] == 7 &`.

*Update for version 12.1*

In version 12.1, [OperatorApplied](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OperatorApplied.html) is the new name for `Curry`.  The [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Curry.html) for `Curry` states that it is now being phased out.

**Currying The Hard Way**

A rather obscure idiom makes it possible to perform such currying in pure functions, even before version 11.3:

```
Length[
  Select[IntegerPartitions[10], #0[[0]][First[#[1]] == #2] &[Slot, #]]
] & /@ Range[10]

(* {1, 5, 8, 9, 7, 5, 3, 2, 1, 1} *)
```

The cryptic expression `#0[[0]][First[#[1]] == #2]&[Slot, #]` performs the necessary currying.  `#0[[0]]` expands to `Function`.  The disguised use of the symbol `Function` is necessary to avoid shadowing the inner slot references.  `#[1]` expands to `Slot[1]`, i.e. `#1`.  `#2` expands to the value of the outer `#`.  So, if the outer `#` were `7`, then we would get `First[#1] == 7 &` as desired.

This construction is likely too ugly to actually use.  Thank goodness for the arrival of `Curry` :)

Comment: This is a nice use case I for one had not anticipated.

Answer (score 8):

This is probably not going to be the best answer but offering it as an opener or as a guide to towards a better solution

Setting your initial input as a function

```
f[n_]:=Length[Select[IntegerPartitions[10],First[#]==n&]]
```

then

```
Map[f,Range[10]]
```

> ```
> {1, 5, 8, 9, 7, 5, 3, 2, 1, 1}
> ```

No doubt regular contributors can improve on this

Answer (score 5):

You can also perform this without "netsted functions" issue. For example:

```
Count[IntegerPartitions[10][[All, 1]], #] & /@ Range[10]
```

It could be even faster but we have to assume that you know the output of `IntegerPartitions` (*explained on the bottom*):

```
Reverse @ Tally[IntegerPartitions[10][[All, 1]]][[All, 2]]
```

*Description*

- `IntegerPartitions[10]`**`[[All, 1]]`** because only first elements are important
- `[[All, 2]]` after `Tally` -> here we assume that we know that there will be a set of values from 1 to 10, otherwise some sort of filtering is needed.
- `Reverse` because `IntegerPartitions` list values are decreasing.