# How to supply argument to pure function when slot is already defined?

Tags: pure-function, slot, arguments

Here's an example of a pure function:

```
3^# > 100 &
```

I can supply any value I please to the function, by placing that value after the prefix. E.g.:

```
3^# > 100 & @ 8
```

> True

But suppose we have a pure function that already has an argument.  E.g., here the argument is `{2, 6, 8, 4}`:

```
AllTrue[{2, 6, 8, 4}, # < 10 &]
```

> True

Further suppose I want to create a new pure function that takes the test value in the inequality as an argument.  I.e., instead of using a fixed test value (in this case, 10), I want the function to be able to take any test value.

I can accomplish this using a traditional function definition:

```
f[n_] := AllTrue[{2, 6, 8, 4}, # < n &]
f[10]
```

> True

But is there a simple way to accomplish this entirely with a pure function?  In pseudocode, it would look something like this, where the value after the prefix is inserted in place of the `?`:

```
AllTrue[{2, 6, 8, 4}, # < ? &] @ 10
```

> True

Comment: You can use `Function` with named arguments to avoid the collision, e.g `(n |-> (#<n&))[10]`. (Replace the `|->` with `\[Function]` if you are using an older version)

Comment: ..., i. e., `AllTrue[{2, 6, 8, 4}, x |-> x <#] & @ 10`.

Comment: Or `Function[n, AllTrue[{2, 6, 8, 4}, # < n &]]` or if you prefer more verbose code.

Comment: Although not an answer to the general question you ask, for the example you cite you could use `AllTrue[{2, 6, 8, 4,11}, LessThan[#]]&[10]` (or `AllTrue[{2, 6, 8, 4}, LessThan[#]]&/@{10,8}`)?

Comment: Thanks everyone.  As an alternative to, say, `f[n_] := AllTrue[First /@ FactorInteger@n, #∣(n/# - 1) &]; f[30]`, why does `Function[n, 
  AllTrue[First /@ FactorInteger@n, #∣(n/# - 1) &]]@30` work, but `AllTrue[First /@ FactorInteger@#, 
   (n |-> n)∣(#/(n |-> n) - 1)] &@30` does not?

Comment: @theorist Because `(n |-> n)∣(#/(n |-> n) - 1)` asks for the divisibility of two functions, which is not defined. Check `InputForm[AllTrue[First /@ FactorInteger@#, (n |-> n)\[Divides](#/(n |-> n) - 1)] &]` to see what goes wrong.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit  Well yes, but I was asking why that doesn't work.   I thought, from kglr's example, that the principle was one substitutes `x |-> x` (or whatever variable you please) for #, since that effectively says "this argument is used internally", and then substitutes `#` for `n` to introduce the value from outside.  Thus that's what I did with the `FactorInteger` syntax.  But that doesn't work in that case.    Perhaps if you could give me the correct non-verbose syntax (i.e., using `n |-> n`) for that example, I could better understand the underlying concept.

Comment: @theorist This is the exact reason I don't like glyphs like  `|->`: it's just not all that clear what they mean to many people. Here's a version of that code that does work: `AllTrue[First /@ FactorInteger@#, n |-> n\[Divides](#/n - 1)]&`. Be sure to check the `InputForm` or `FullForm` of that as well.

Comment: @theorist Oh, and one more thing: the notation `x -> x^2` is short for `Function[x, x^2]`. That's what it means, just to be clear on that.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Did you perhaps instead mean to write "`x |-> x^2` is short for `Function[x, x^2]`"?  I ask because it's my understanding that `->` means "Rule" and `|->` means "Function".  And thanks for your expanations—they look like they'll be very helpful in aiding my understanding; I'll review them tomorrow.

Comment: @theorist Ah, yes. You're right. I mistyped it. It should have been `x |-> x^2`.

Comment: I am not fully sure of my ground here, but on reading [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/197168/106) by wreach, `AllTrue[{2, 6, 8, 4}, CurryApplied[#2<# &,2][#]]& @ 10 (* True *)`.  For example, `AllTrue[{2, 6, 8, 4}, CurryApplied[#2<# &,2][#]]& /@ {8,10} (* False, True *)`.  In addition, `AllTrue[{2, 6, 8, 4}, OperatorApplied[#2<# &,2][#]]& @ 10`

Comment: Just for fun: `AllTrue[First/@FactorInteger[#], CurryApplied[#2∣(#1/#2 - 1)&,2][#]]&/@Range[30]`

Comment: @SjoerdSmit  As an exercise, I've tried using `|->` in other applications where I need to avoid variable collision, but can't figure out how to make it work here, even after looking at its FullForm:  `rf = {{6, 3}, {3, 5}, {0, 2}, {3, 0}};
(r = #; Mean@r - # & /@ r) &@rf`.  I was wondering if you might be able to tell me what would be the equivalent syntax with `|->`.

Comment: You mean like `(r |-> Mean[r] - # & /@ r) @ rf`?

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Yes, thanks!  With that last example, I think I'm starting to see a pattern in how this works.  For instance, with `AllTrue[{2, 6, 8, 4}, n |-> n < #] &@10` $\equiv$ `AllTrue[{2, 6, 8, 4}, Function[n, n < #]] &@10`, the external argument (10) is fed to `#`, and the local variable (n) is used to create an internal function that takes each successive element of {2,4,6,8} and compares it with 10.  By contrast, with `(r |-> Mean@r - # & /@ r)@rf `  $\equiv$ `(Function[r, Mean@r - # & /@ r])@rf`, the `&` after the `#` indicates the `#` is being used internally for a pure function, and

Comment: ...thus the external argument (rf) is fed into the local variable (r) instead of to `#`.   Alas, I tried applying this to a somewhat more complicated problem, in which I have two external arguments, but was unable to see how to use the `|->` syntax there:   `(a = #1; b = #2 ; AllTrue[a, # < b &]) & @@ {{2, 4, 6, 8}, 10}`.  If you wouldn't mind, I'd be very interested to see how one would construct that using `|->`.   Also, might you happen to know anywhere I could find a tutorial on this?  Wolfram's documentation doesn't seem to cover this type of use of `Function`.

Comment: @theorist: `({a, b} |-> AllTrue[a, # < b &]) @@ {{2, 4, 6, 8}, 10}`. It's described (tersely) at the top of the [doc page of Function](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you don't want to follow some suggestions made in comments and use the `Function` with named arguments (and there may be valid reasons to be willing to avoid that), you can use `With` instead:

```
fn = With[{n = #}, AllTrue[{2, 6, 8, 4}, # < n &]] &
```

So that

```
{fn[5], fn[10]}

(* {False, True} *)
```

Comment: I like that construction because of its intuitive nature.  Plus it led me to realize it can be written even more simply as: `(n = #; AllTrue[{2, 6, 8, 4}, # < n &]) &`.  Are there examples in which this wouldn't work, and you would need `With`?

Comment: @theorist Your version introduces `n` as a global variable, which is generally a bad idea. You could wrap your code in `Module` (or, in this case, `Block`), to localize it, like e.g. `Block[{n}, (n = #; AllTrue[{2, 6, 8, 4}, # < n &]) &]`. But then it essentially becomes the same as using `With`. Using `With` seems the cleanest of such methods here, since we know that `n` is not going to change inside the code. As to examples of failures: in your case, the predicate `# < n &` is very simple. There could be more complex ones defined separately and referring to global `n`, which could fail.