# How to use Select and MemberQ together with Map correctly?

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering, map

I have a list with quite a few elements. Each element is a rule of the type `vector-> number` such as `{1,2,3,4}->1.435` and all possible permutations of the vector of the rule are present, so I also have elements like `{1,3,4,2}-> 1.325` and so on. I would like to select all elements of the list which have a permutation of a given vector as the first part of the rule. I'm trying to use `Select` together with `MemberQ`and `Apply`. The code I wrote, and which is not working, is like this:

```
Select[list, MemberQ[#1, #2, 2] &] /@ Permutations[vector]
```

I guess I simply don't know how to `Map` with respect to the second argument of MemberQ, which in this case should be the permutations of the vector, and leave the first argument of the pure function `MemberQ` to be substituted by the elements of the list.

What does work, but I find somewhat ugly is

```
Table[Select[list, MemberQ[#, Permutations[vector][[i]],2] &],{i,1,Length[Permutations[vector]]}]
```

I could also write something using `Module`, but I want it to be more compact. Can you help me?

Comment: try if  `Select[list, Function[x,MemberQ[x,#, 2] ]]& /@ Permutations[vector]` or `Function[p,Select[list,MemberQ[#,p,2]&]]/@Permutations[vector]` gives what you need.

Comment: Thank you very much, @kglr. That works! Great! So, Function was the missing ingredient, I see now.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to nest pure functions: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38393/pure-function-inside-another-pure-function?rq=1

Comment: Selecting members might be written as an Intersection

Comment: Yes, @march, I guess this is the same as was suggested by kglr.