# ReplacePart with processed value

Tags: list-manipulation

To illustrate, suppose I want to change the `{2,2}` element of a matrix.  If I know the replacement value, I can just make the replacement.

```
ReplacePart[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {2, 2} -> 5]
```

But what if I need to process the value to get its replacement?  Of course, I could create a symbol and process it.

```
mA = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
mA[[2, 2]] = f[mA[[2,2]]]
```

But I'd rather work directly with the value and not create a new symbol.  Possible?

Comment: Take a look at `MapAt`.

Comment: Can it be something like: ReplacePart[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {2, 2} -> f[#]] &[(*value*)]

Comment: @Alan, as a sort of delusions, `mA[[2, 2]] = mA[[2, 2]] // Function[x, x + 1]; mA`

Comment: worth noting [link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16947/second-level-depth-pure-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};

process[x_] := x + 1

ReplacePart[list, # :> process@Extract[list, #]] &[{2, 2}]
```

> {{1, 2}, {3, 5}}

As commented by @Kuba the more natural choice would be

```
MapAt[process, list, {2, 2}]
```

> {{1, 2}, {3, 5}}

Comment: You're processing 5, not the 4 in position {2, 2}

Answer (score 1):

**Code:**

```
ReplacePart[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {2, 2} -> f[#]] &[5]
```

**Output:**

> {{1, 2}, {3, f[5]}}

**Reference:**

[ReplacePart](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplacePart.html)

**EDIT 1:**
Based on comment left by *@SimonWoods*, please consult adjusted implementation below:

**Code:**

```
(*Sample*)
list = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};

(*Dummy function*)
f[x_] := x + 1;

(*Operation*)   
ReplacePart[list, # -> f[list[[2, 2]]]] &[{2, 2}]
```

**Output:**

> {{1, 2}, {3, 5}}

Comment: This is not what the question asks for - the idea is to apply `f` to the matrix element at position {2,2}

Comment: @SimonWoods I must have misunderstood the OPs question, would following adjustment be a better fit: ReplacePart[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, # -> f[#]] &[{2, 2}] ?