# Soft question: Is it feasible to have argument names with the shorthand (&) pure function syntax?

Tags: pure-function

Nested pure functions can be [messy](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16948/55405), code length wise and syntax wise. It seems that the ampersand (&) in pure functions is always either proceeded by nothing:

```
list // SortBy[#, Last[#]] &
Select[list, First[#]==="potato" &]
```

or is proceeded by a special operator:

```
{#, f[#]} & @ item
g[#,f[#]] & /@ list
(#1 -> #2) & @@@ list
f[g[#1, #2], h[#1, #2]] & [a, b]
```

Which leads me to wonder—at the risk of being off topic—is it feasible for argument names to be used in the shorthand notation by having it precede the ampersand symbol? Or is there some unforeseen use case in Mathematica which makes this impossible? Hopefully the yes-no question will make it on topic.

To illustrate this, here are some methods of nesting pure functions, the first two are from [kglr](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/125/kglr)'s linked answer above, and the last is based off [Henrik Schumacher](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/38178/henrik-schumacher)'s comment:

```
Function[{x}, Select[x, # == Nearest[x, 4.][[1]] &]] /@ lists
With[{x = Nearest[#1, 4.`][[1]]}, Select[#1, # == x &]] & /@ lists
# /. x_ :> Select[x, # == Nearest[x, 4.][[1]] &] & /@ lists
(x \[Function] Select[x, # == Nearest[x, 4.][[1]] &]) /@ lists
```

Here is the same code using the hypothetical method:

```
Select[x, # == Nearest[x, 4.][[1]] &] & x /@ lists
```

and here is how multiple arguments would look:

```
{f[x], g[y]} & {x, y} @@@ lists
```

I didn't include patterns as it seems like `Module`, `With` and the shorthand method are not able to use them.

Comment: And for comparison, `a & b` currently evaluates to `b (a &)` or `Times[b, Function[a]]` in full form. Edit: Was responding to deleted comment about `a & b` potentially being evaluated as `Function[b, a]`.

Comment: https://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node210.html

Comment: Maybe you are just looking for the infix form `\[Function]` of `Function`?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher That's pretty neat actually, I didn't know there was a symbol for it. I'm not sure how different it it is to the third example though, and it would need encompassing brackets around the whole function. I'll update my question to include it.

Comment: You could setup your own notation for `Function` with the Notation package but why would you want to obfuscate your code like this?

Comment: @Edmund Awesome, I'll check it out. My code might already be obfuscated... I'm a sucker for Mathematica's shorthand pure functions, especially when manipulating data in lists. I don't like defining single use functions; maybe it's a bad habit. It's gotten me very interested in functional programming though.

Comment: `Notation` does not seem to be working with patterns. Even the given example doesn't work. I'll try updating Mathematica and see if that helps.

Comment: The example at https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Notation/tutorial/ComplexPatternsAndAdvancedFeatures.html for complex patterns do not seem to work. The example is not getting converted into `foo[Pi]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to agree with Henrik Schumacher's comment and advice to use infix form of `Function`:

[image]

Infix form (the arrow) can be easily entered using <kbd>Esc</kbd>`fn`<kbd>Esc</kbd> or `\[Function]`

Comment: Oh my. I have not see this before!! Does it serve the same purpose as an ampersand? Or a combo of piping and ampersand?